# What is a good way to make a session value available to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, .net, html, client-server

When my page loads, it stores an id from the database into session: `Session["AppId"] = 1234`. However, when I am doing JavaScript stuff, I need to know that AppId for database calls. How can I make that available to my JS from the server code? Would registering a script tag with `var appId = 1234` be the way to go or does that code smell a bit too ripe?

Would adding a custom-attribute to the body tag make more sense? `data-appid=1234` for example?

I'm new to web stuff, so the do's and don't's aren't always obvious to me. If there's a right/best way, feel free to share it.

### EDIT:

The solution I actually needed was `HttpContext.Current.Session["AppId"]`. I didn't think static methods could access session values, so I thought I had to store it in the mark-up to pass to my WebMethod through an Ajax call. I accepted the answer I did because it answered the question I asked. I just asked the wrong question. =) I'm new remember - go easy on me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

- As you posted, a `data-*` attribute
- A hidden form field (if you have a form on the page)
- Embed in the URL
- Output to javascript into a variable

There is no consensus on which is best.

Comment: You can also embed a dynamic JSON file which is generated by a PHP script.

Comment: @ComFreek - You are assuming PHP.

Comment: You're right but JSON should be producible by almost every language.

Comment: @Oded A dev here brought up IRequiresSessionState. He made it seem like I could just use the interface on my aspx.cs file, however that doesn't seem to work. Is that doable?

Comment: @Yatrix - I don't follow? What's that got to do with your question? `IRequiresSessionState` is just a marker interface. It does nothing on its own.

Comment: @Oded He mentioned using it to expose Session values to the static page methods my JavaScript is using for db calls. If that were possible, I wouldn't have to store them in the mark-up at all. I wasn't aware a static method could access Session values since they don't have access to Page. I had already posted this question when he mentioned it.

Comment: @Yatrix - `Session` is a global object. You should be able to use it if accessible. From the documentation on `IRequiresSessionState` it appears to only apply to HTTP Handlers, so I don't know how your colleague expects it to work - but you might as well try.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a hidden field or use a global variable.

Hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" value='<%= Session["AppId"] %>'></input>
```

Global variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.AppId = '<%= Session["AppId"] %>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

personally I output the session value to a global variable like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["AppId"]))
    {
        echo "var AppId=".$_SESSION["AppId"].";";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "var AppId=null;";
    }
    ?>
</script>
```

## Alternatively...

while I'm not sure how your client side app function, could you not check the AppID value server side when actually making the database query?

This way the AppID value is never shown to the user, and they wont be able to mess with the value via javascript.

Comment: The AppId isn't important. It's just so the database knows what dataset to return. The data has no meaning that could be harmful.